# Selecting a result from gpresult /r

Tags: powershell

Can anyone help me piping the return value from gpresult /r

I need to get the value from the roaming profile line in the gpresult /r, example below

Roaming Profile: `\\servername\somepath$\username\.V2`

I want to pipe just the `\\servername\somepath$\username\` only into a string like $profilepath, the 'servername' varies though from branch to branch.

I need this to be done on Powershell, this is what I've got but I want to have something that's more stable:

```
$properties = gpresult /r

if (Select-String -Pattern "server1" -InputObject $properties) { $server="server1" }
if (Select-String -Pattern "server2" -InputObject $properties) {$server="server2" } $profilepath="\\$server\somepath$\$($env:USERNAME)\
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You need to capture the output and parse it to extract the string you're looking for. Show the code you've tried and where you're stuck with it.

Comment: $properties = gpresult /r
if (Select-String -Pattern "server1" -InputObject $properties) { $server="server1" }
if (Select-String -Pattern "server2" -InputObject $properties) {$server="server2" }

$profilepath="\\$server\somepath$\$($env:USERNAME)\

This is what I've got, I want to have something that's more stable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you care about is the roaming profile line you can just use:

```
$properties = gpresult /r
$line = $properties | Select-String "Roaming Profile:" | select -ExpandProperty Line
$line
Roaming Profile:             N/A
```

You can then just split the string on the :

```
$line -split ':'
Roaming Profile
            N/A
```

Grab the second member

```
($line -split ':')[1]
        N/A
```

And Trim if needed

```
($line -split ':')[1].Trim()
N/A
```